# How to skip a specific word when replace the String using regexp in java

Tags: java, regex, string

Consider the string

```
String s = "H_ello pe_rfec_t wor_ld"
```

I want to replace all '_' symbols on... no matter what, let`s say on '1', except those which are placed inside the 'pe_rfec_t'.
I could not find any solution even to just skip the word 'pe_rfec_t':

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=pe_rfec_t).*|.*(?=pe_rfec_t)", "1");
```

looks nice at a glance but results to:

```
11pe_rfec_t1 //instead of 1111111pe_rfec_t1111111
```

Ideally I need the following result:

```
Hello pe_rfec_t world
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Probably relevant: [link](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: Split the String into words, then apply a simple regular expression to all relevant words (skipping "perfect").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use alternation and captured group:

```
String str = "H_ello pe_rfec_t wor_ld";

String repl = str.replaceAll("(pe_rfec_t)|_", "$1");
//=> Hello pe_rfec_t world
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hCL1WB/2)

Here in alternation we match first `pe_rfec_t` and capture it in group #1. In repalcement we put `$1` (back-reference to group #1) back.

Comment: Just FYI: if anyone wants to replace `_` with `1`, this solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a presise and elegant desicion of my issue